# How do I completely disable "proposals" popups for javascript in Eclipse?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, wildwebdeveloper

I'm trying to prevent these irritating popups in Eclipse.

The popups show up while I'm trying to type lines of code, "helpfully" making proposals but ultimately just getting in the way and making arrow keys not work as expected.

Screenshot:
[image]

I've searched for instructions on how to disable this, but none of the things suggested in other links seem to work.

I've tried disabling all "hovers" and unchecking everything on the Java Proposals page in the Eclipse preferences dialog, but that's had no effect in the javascript editor.

I've tried searching the Eclipse Preferences for "javascript" but that doesn't show any Editor page, and none of the preference pages that are shown for javascript seem to have any options to disable proposals.

How do I disable these popups in the javascript editor?

Comment: In the preferences _Language Servers_ you can disable the language server for JavaScript. Unfortunately, [you didn't tell your real problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), so there might be a better solution for your issue (there is no code example and the cropped screenshot is not helpful either).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Code example is irrelevant — the problem isn't specific to any particular code, it's a problem with the IDE that applies to all javascript code. Also I was pretty clear in the first line that the real problem is irritating popups getting in the way. Anyway thanks again for the suggestion, disabling the language server for js seems to have done the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Just making @howlger's comment into an official answer in case anyone encounters the same issue with Eclipse "Proposals" popup annoyances.

The solution was to go into the Preferences, search for "Language", then in the "Language Servers" list I unchecked "JavaScript" and applied the changes.

No more popups!

Thanks again @howlger

Comment: Seems a little extreme. Are you able to get proposals at all with this change?

Comment: No, this has successfully suppressed all JavaScript proposals (which was the goal).

Comment:  But what if you want them sometimes? Like how other editors work?

Comment: I've never once found them useful, all they do is add extra keystrokes to my workflow. I don't anticipate ever wanting them sometimes — it's more likely I'll end up disabling them in other editors at some point in the future. Thanks for your concern though  :)  I'll cross that bridge in the unlikely event I ever come to it.